# Why do they use "her" for Titanic?

Tags: possessives, gender

I was reading [the Wikipedia's page on RMS Titanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Titanic) and just noticed numerous references to the ship by possessive **her**.

Why don't they simply use **"its"** for Titanic?

Comment: I don`t know but the same applies to cars.

Comment: This is a well-established meaning of the feminine pronoun, listed in most [dictionaries](http://wordnik.com/words/she). (See also [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/she?a=british).)

Comment: By tradition, all naval vessels, both small and large, are considered **female**.  I doubt very much this tradition is limited to English speakers.

Comment: So, is it incorrect to use "its" for them?

Comment: @OmidR - That’s not what anyone is saying. In English, there are almost always multiple correct ways to say something.

Comment: @J.R. Cambridge Dictionary says it is an old-fashioned use.

Comment: @OmidR - I can understand that, but I wouldn’t argue that vehemently. You should poke around and see how many other dictionaries call it old-fashioned. If you start at [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=she&ls=a), you’ll have plenty to examine. [AH](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=she) uses a Bruce Springsteen quote as a usage example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, especially in a poetic description, ships are referred to as "*she*". This may be--no, it must be--because the owners of the ships, yachts, and ferries as well,  compare their beauty and elegance with those of women.

Comment: It might be elegance; it might also be fondness, or it might even be temperament. Whatever it is, it’s an interesting quirk of the language. English, she is a strange language indeed.

Comment: @J.R. "English, she is a strange language indeed". Do you mean that speaking of any other language, **he** may not be strange? Pardon my ignorance, but "Could languages really be sorted out by the gender?" A bewildered learner asks.

Comment: Were it not for the OP’s question, I don’t think I would have used a gender pronoun at all. I was merely making a humorous comment based on the context. My normal way of saying this would be: _English is indeed a strange language_.

Answer (score -1):

It Is because she (ship, country, and vehicle) carry people the same way mothers do, so both are compared the same way.

Comment: Would be better if you add sources/reference.